# Capistrano 3. To set bash shell on server instead csh

Tags: shell, capistrano3, sshkit

When cap3 try to execute comands on my FreeBSD server - I have an errors and my cap3 tasks doesn't work

```
DEBUG [0bb99d53] Command: if test ! -d /home/web_server/data/www/capistrano/site/shared/dumps; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/web_server/data/www/capistrano/site/shared/dumps'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [0bb99d53]    if: Expression Syntax.
DEBUG [0bb99d53]    fi: Command not found.
```

And I know why - because my server use csh shell by default

```
% echo $0
-csh
```

Following cap3 variable doesn't work for me

```
set :shell, '/usr/local/bin/bash'
set :default_shell, '/usr/local/bin/bash'
```

How can I set shell for cap3 tasks?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the default shell to bash for the deploy user on your server.

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash [your_deploy_user]
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that you can attempt to use:

```
/bin/bash -c 'if test ! -d /home/web_server/data/www/capistrano/site/shared/dumps; then echo "Directory does not exist \'/home/web_server/data/www/capistrano/site/shared/dumps\'" 1>&2; false; fi'
```

> From the Bash man page:
>
> If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string. If
>   there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the
>   positional parameters, starting with $0.
>
> I did a test and it worked for me:
>
> ```
> 1@one:~>%bash -c "/bin/echo Hello; echo Goodbye"
> Hello
> Goodbye
> ```